# Calculating local time offset from GMT time

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I only have GMT time without any offset, example 15:00:00, my requirement is to find out what timezone this GMT time belongs to, I have tried to solve it by using my local time and converting it to GMT time and doing some comparison but I don't think that it might be the right way to do it.

Comment: Share your code and we can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: You do know that GMT *is* a timezone? England and Portugal use it during the winter.

Comment: @Bathsheba it seems appropriate to add *ahem* Scotland :)

Comment: Really? Maybe you need to check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time

Comment: @LuísRamalho Aha! Not quite yet ;)

Comment: I don't think he's asking to convert GMT to a timezone, I think what he's saying is that he has a current time but no offset (ie no reference as to what time zone that time is being given in) and is trying to work out the offset.

eg the time right now is 14:42, so if the time given was 18:42, he's trying to find the offset (ie +4)

zakSyed, I think you need to clarify your question, but my advice would be to convert everything to UTC, not GMT. UTC should always be used where possible for times, and then display the time on the local machine based on the locally calculated offset.

Comment: (@LuísRamalho: Scotland can get it's own time zone, they're not having ours.)

Comment: @Sharpy310, it is a country. Just not independent yet.

Comment: @JonStory, that would be awesome! :)

Comment: @JonStory the time I am getting is from an external system in that format, so I can't control it. The explanation you have given is what I am trying to do,

Comment: @zakSyed, so you're getting a time of "right now" from whatever source, but need to compare that to GMT? And it's definitely a GMT time, not UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the time is definitely offset from GMT, you should be able to produce a GMT timestamp using the following, and then compare the two. Your resulting answer, converted back to hours, should be the offset, which you can then lookup.

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Note that this doesn't take into account daylight savings/summer time etc, and assumes that the time given is right now, and can therefore be compared to the current GMT time. Specifically, remember that a timezone can fluctuate by a couple of hours if, like the UK and Australia, their summer/winter periods are reversed, so a +11 hour time zone offset may actually be +10 or +12 at any given point in time. And some countries don't use DST at all, even in the same time zone.

Note also that the entire point of time zone offsets and use of a centralised time (eg UTC) is to avoid the above confusion. By definition, you're doing things the long way round and introducing levels of uncertainty.

You may therefore have one country in the northern hemisphere varying +/- 1 hour, one in the southern varying -/+ 1 hour, and one near the equator using the same time constantly... and you'd have no idea which ones are meant to be in that time zone. You can find the offset, but that's about it.